# SPFX - Webpart properties not appearing in search results

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have created spfx webpart which just displays the webpart property.
Following is the code.

[image]

[image]

"Hello" string is stored in my webpart property.

**Issue**:
When I try to search the webpart property content nothing appears in search results

but When I search "WebPartID+propertycontent", the page is displayed in the search results. AS you can see in following image the webpartid is appearing concatenated with the Webpart property.

[image]